# dblclick event of jQuery not working in my code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

The dblclick event of jQuery  is not working. When I replace dblclick with just click then it's working perfectly fine. I don't understand the problem.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery Selectors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2 class="first" id="firstH2">Selectors up jQuery-2</h2>
    <p>Paragraph free of any division</p>
    <div class="mydivs" id="firstdiv">
        <p>This is 1st para in 1st div</p>
        <p>This is 2nd para in 1st div</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mydivs" id="seconddiv">
        <p>This is 3rd para in 2nd div</p>
    </div>
    <button onclick="fn1()" id="btn1">Click Me</button>
    <button id="btn2" onclick="fn1()">Click Me 2</button>
</body>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn1").dblclick(fn1);
        function fn1(){
            $("#firstdiv").fadeToggle();
        }
        $("#btn2").dblclick(function(){
            $("#seconddiv").fadeToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you have regular onclicks inline calling same thing as the dblclick.... Do you realize onclick still runs with dblclick? so when you double click you are calling `fn1(); fn1(); fn1()`

Comment: Whats the reason you are using inline `onclick` and `dblclick` at the same time. That might be causing the issue.

Comment: Also, small side note, the different implementations of applying a dblclick callback between the two elements is a code smell to me.  I have to stop and ask myself why you did that.  Edit: probably because fn1 is being used as the inline binding, so, meh.

Comment: I am just learning javascript and jquery and hence I am not well acquainted with the working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to write inline click event and no need to add separate function. Check update snippet below...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").dblclick(function(){
      $("#firstdiv").fadeToggle();
    });
    $("#btn2").dblclick(function(){
        $("#seconddiv").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="first" id="firstH2">Selectors up jQuery-2</h2>
<p>Paragraph free of any division</p>
<div class="mydivs" id="firstdiv">
    <p>This is 1st para in 1st div</p>
    <p>This is 2nd para in 1st div</p>
</div>
<div class="mydivs" id="seconddiv">
    <p>This is 3rd para in 2nd div</p>
</div>
<button id="btn1">Click Me</button>
<button id="btn2">Click Me 2</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the click handler from the markup and just use your event handler code.

```js
$(function() {
  function fn1(event) {
    $("#firstdiv").fadeToggle();
  }
  $("#btn1").on('dblclick', fn1);

  $("#btn2").dblclick(function() {
    $("#seconddiv").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="first" id="firstH2">Selectors up jQuery-2</h2>
<p>Paragraph free of any division</p>
<div class="mydivs" id="firstdiv">
  <p>This is 1st para in 1st div</p>
  <p>This is 2nd para in 1st div</p>
</div>
<div class="mydivs" id="seconddiv">
  <p>This is 3rd para in 2nd div</p>
</div>
<button id="btn1">Click Me</button>
<button id="btn2">Click Me 2</button>
```

Comment: Not sure why the down vote, please elaborate why this does not answer the question.

Comment: Comments are not answers and I was already typing this answer and testing it.

Comment: FWIW if the OP wants to have BOTH `onclick` and `ondblclick` that is really another question.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I disagree in this case (and if it were a simple typo there is a close reason for that), opinions vary and I have no objections to opinions, I have some also ;)

Comment: No worries. Good effort  :)

Answer (score 1):

Onclick and Dbclick cant work on same buttons.

Onclick is triggered first and dbclick is blocked